# Behavior of C++ `auto' keyword with compiler optimization level

Tags: c++, optimization

In general, should the type deduced by the `auto`-keyword be invariant to compiler optimization level? Or is it consistent with the language-standard if `g++ -O3` and `g++ -g`, say, result in different types being deduced for the `auto' keyword for the same line of code?

I have a function, call it func(), which returns a uint8_t and I've noticed that if I do:

```
auto val = func();
```

Then val ends up as a `uint8_t` without optimizations and a 4-byte type (so, apparently `uint32_t`) with optimization.

Related question, since I can't do `sizeof()` on the return-type of a function ... what can I do to get the size of a function return type that isn't influenced by compiler optimizations?

Comment: No, these are completely orthogonal mechanisms. Give us a [MCVE] to proof that please.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that show this please.

Comment: @ πάντα  Apparently not, according to the OP's question.

Comment: That's not how it is generally supposed to work. There are a few rare exceptions where it could, but in the cases I can think of, either it should be obvious that it could depend on optimisation, or it actually doesn't do what you think it does, just looks like it. Do you have some minimal code to reproduce the problem, so that it can be determined whether any exceptions apply?

Comment: Hmm. Can types such as `int_fast16_t` provide different sizes at different optimization levels, since there is no one mandated result for that declaration?

Comment: Thankfully I think I'm off-base in the issue that I'm having ... it's probably not related to the auto keyword.

I have templated functions involved. It appears that my `debug' binary appropriately calls the explicit template specialization in one instance ... but the 'release' binary seems to ignore the explicit specialization and uses the generic template version instead.

I'll figure this out. Sorry to cast aspersions on 'auto'. Haha.

Comment: @MatthewM. So you were _barking up the wrong tree_?

Comment: Sure was. I guess I'll hold off on posting a question about why optimization level has an impact on which templated function is being called... in case that's the wrong tree as well.

Comment: @MatthewM. As mentioned type deduction and optimization are orthogonal things.

Comment: Okay. Figured it out. My full specializations weren't explicitly declared in the header file; only defined in the source file. So, my un-optimized build managed to find the specializations... the optimized build never did (but didn't complain because it had a template it could use). ... did the optimized build consider them `unreachable' and never link them, maybe?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't do `sizeof()` on the return-type of a function"?  Did you try `sizeof(func())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the size of the return type for a function, use sizeof for the function with its argument types (in this case null).

So, in your case, you would find the size of the return type by:

```
auto WhatsMySize = sizeof(func());
```

You can even put in an assertion to check that the return type is the one you expected--for example, to check to see whether overloading worked as expected:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(func()), int>::value,
   "func has incorrect return value");
```

Comment: The emitted assembly might differ from that though. I'm thinking about cache lining optimizaiton and such. Let the OP clarify 1st before answering  please.

Comment: The first argument of `std::result_of` must be a type, which `func()` is not.  You can just do `sizeof(func())` (which does not call `func`).  `sizeof(func)` is ill-formed, not undefined behavior.

Comment: Yikes, you're right. I confused `invoke_result` with `result of`. Fixed it now.

Comment: `func` is still not a type.  You could do `invoke_result<decltype(func)>`, but I still don't see the advantage over `sizeof(func())` or `is_same<decltype(func()),...`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get for trying to answer something that is at the edge of my knowledge. Corrected.